# How to run a process in background, after getting a user input in bash shell

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

INPUT_NO_OF_PROCESS=$1
NO_OF_PROCESS="${INPUT_NO_OF_PROCESS:-1}"

#mkdir -p $DUMP_DIR
echo "Spawning processes=$NO_OF_PROCESS"


for i in $(seq 1 $NO_OF_PROCESS)
do
    # This command will expect a password and has to be spawned
    # into multiple processes after getting the password
    some_command_that_expects_password&
done
```

The above bash script fails to get the password, if it's started as a background process **&**

Is there any way to get inputs and let the process then go background?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

Only the `command_with_password` knows when the password is typed (with possible retries). So only the command can determine when it is OK to go into the background.

You might be able to do something with a second script, that watches the first script and sends a SIGTSTP (`kill -20`) to the program and then background it, but that is not an easy hack.

It also depends on how the password is asked. In some cases, wrapping your `cmd_with_password` in an `expect` script would be an option.